# button is not clicked in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

## Env

- python 3.8.17
- selenium 4.11.2
- chrome version : 115.0.5790.170 (arm64)

## Problem

[image]

The Register button in the screenshot above is not clicked in Selenium.

### Error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (600, 841)
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.170)
```

using developer tools, `section tags` are returned to this coordinate
[image]
The `section tag` is the highest parent tag

### html full code

```html
    <body>
    <!-- Loader -->
    <div id="preloader" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
        <div id="status">
            <div class="spinner">
                <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Loader -->
    
    <div class="back-to-home rounded d-none d-sm-block">
        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home icons"><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline></svg></a>
    </div>
    
    <section class="bg-half-150 d-table w-100 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8">
                    <img src="/static/layout/images/logo-marp.png" height="60" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="">
                    <div class="card login-page bg-white shadow mt-4 rounded border-0">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="text-center">Sign Up</h4>
                            <form action="/signup" method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Username <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus="" class="form-control" required="" id="id_username">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Email address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" class="form-control" id="id_email">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" required="" id="id_password1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Password confirmation <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="password" name="password2" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" required="" id="id_password2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Region <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="region" maxlength="200" class="form-control" required="" id="id_region">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label class="form-label">Phone number <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="phone_number" maxlength="200" class="form-control" required="" id="id_phone_number">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="d-grid">
    
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" name="register" id="register">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    
                                    
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div><!---->
                </div> <!--end col-->
            </div><!--end row-->
        </div> <!--end container-->
    </section>
    <!-- Hero End -->
    <!-- Login Page End Here -->
    <!-- jquery-->
    <script src="/static/layout/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/layout/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- simplebar -->
    <script src="/static/layout/js/simplebar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="/static/layout/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/layout/js/select2.init.js"></script>
    <!-- Icons -->
    <script src="/static/layout/js/feather.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Main Js -->
    <script src="/static/layout/js/app.js"></script>
    
    
    
    </body>
```

### seleninum code

```py
def find_and_send(self, by, key, values):
    target = self.selenium.find_element(by, key)
    target.send_keys(values)
    self.selenium = WebDriver()
    self.selenium.implicitly_wait(100)

   # insert field value

def main(self):
    self.selenium.get("{}/signup".format(self.live_server_url))
    self.find_and_send(By.NAME, "username", id)
    self.find_and_send(By.ID, "id_email", "testuser0@publicai.co.kr")
    self.find_and_send(By.NAME, "password1", "q1w2e3r4Q!W@E#R$")
    self.find_and_send(By.NAME, "password2", "q1w2e3r4Q!W@E#R$")
    self.find_and_send(By.NAME, "region", "seoul")
    self.selenium.find_element(By.NAME, "phone_number").clear()
    self.find_and_send(By.NAME, "phone_number", "01000000000")

    # click sign up button
    self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'register').click() # <-- ⚠️ not working!!!
```

## Solve

this problem is solved in the following way.

```py
# click sign up button
self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'register').click()
```

```py
# click sign up button
button=self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'register')
self.selenium.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

## Question

My question is why this problem occurred.

Comment: @JohnGordon tks rely, 
You're right. call `find_element().click()` successfully, but it didn't work. 

I want to find the `button tag`, but selenium retuned `section tag` in selenium.
and i don't know why 

```python 
self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'register').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`ElementClickInterceptedException` is happened, because some element is overlapped your button.

Possible cases:

1. There is invisible overlay / backdrop that was brought to front of the button.
2. Banner / tooltip appeared in front of the button
3. After entering last value loader appeared, so it received an click
4. After entering last value button changed location and click was during element transition state

As far as clicking by JS is force click operation, click was succeeded, ignoring frontend.

Clicking `document.elementFromPoint` that returned section is also make me think that button is changed location.

Possible solutions:

1. If it's backdrop / modal / banner / tooltip / loader - just close it and (or) wait for invisibility
2. Scroll to button via `ActionChains`:

```py
ActionChains(driver).scroll_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

3. Move to element via `ActionChains`:

```py
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```